# charging my customers random amount by paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-sandbox

I am having nightmare figuring out which payment sdk to follow to charge my customers on daily basis for the due outstanding to them from my application which varies(metered charging my customer).

the recurring payment only helps to pay the fixed amount for certain billing cycles.but i have variable amount to charge daily.

Is there any best approach to charge my customers on daily basis for the amount due to them from my software for the digital service i provide to them.

Thanks in advance

any suggestions and comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal offers 3 integration types:
1. [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/) (the most common)
2. [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)
3. [PayPal Payments Pro](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro)

You're trying option #1, which lacks support for variable pries.
Both *Adaptive Payments* and *PayPal Payments Pro* offer recurring charges with dynamic amounts, but require PayPal's approval and quite a bit of paperwork. If you're approved, the APIs are pretty simple in both cases.

May I suggest some easier alternatives?
1. Use [Recurly](https://recurly.com/) who are already approved for #2 above (adaptive payments). Other good alternatives are BrainTree and Stripe.
2. Change your pricing policy to a monthly charge of $X, granting a set of tokens. The user can upgrade to a higher plan to get more tokens every month.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I also want to keep the customer credit card information in paypal by making something like profileId and deducting the amount automatically.I dont want to keep my customers creditcard information in my database.will this API help me to do so.Or this is not allowed by paypal?

Comment: PayPal stores the card information in options #1 and #2 above. As you want to charge dynamic prices, you're left with #2 only, which requires PayPal risk approval.